# If Action Subsystem Output says Inaccessable, why?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'n new to Matlab/Simulink and trying to finish an assignment for my course.
I tried to build a EMS with the help of If Blocks/Actions.
When I run the Simulation everything works fine. As soon as I check the output of the If Block Subsystem its says "Inaccessable". I attached a picture below. What am I doing wrong?

[image: screenshot of Simulink block with error message]

I check if all In- and Outputs are connected.